# Custom WMS Service

Tags: c#, wms

I'm doing an program, which is running on an local system, with no internet access. Is it possible to create my own custom Web Map Service (WMS) server, using C#. I no that there are free open source system's. But i like to have full control. 
Thanks Morten Starck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is very possible, but you might be in for a headache or two before you are done. The implementation specification and more is available from the Open Geospatial Consortium at the url below.

http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/wms

It's quite a large specification but you might be able to get away with implementing only the parts you really need and leaving some of the more specific stuff out. You will of course also need to parse and render the map data from some source which might be your largest problem (for which I really would suggest you have a look at SharpMap, http://sharpmap.codeplex.com/ instead of rolling your own).

Comment: Thanks for that @Karl-Johan Sjögren.  I have been searching for some tutorials about making Sharpmap to act as an wms service. Do you no if something exist??

Comment: There are some stuff relating to WMS (under SharpMapServer so probably not only their client-stuff) in their source tree, I haven't looked at those parts myself though but they are probably worth exploring. http://sharpmap.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/101624#1882294